# unwanted space between random li

Tags: html, html-lists

so I have an ul and a bunch of li. when the list appears, there are random spaces after Franklin & Marshall, Rutgers University, and Tulane University and I cannot figure out why. It's in a bootstrap modal right now but this was a problem prior to this. Please Help. Thanks.

```
                 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Where do you want to visit?</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul id='doubleColumn'>
                                <li>Binghamton University</li>
                                <li>Boston University</li>
                                <li>Carnegie Mellon University</li>
                                <li>Colorado College﻿</li>
                                <li>Emory University</li>
                                <li>Fairfield University</li>
                                <li>Franklin & Marshall</li>
                                ​<li>George Washington University</li>
                                <li>Georgetown University</li>
                                <li>Indiana University</li>
                                <li>Ithaca College</li>
                                <li>Kean University</li>
                                <li>McGill University</li>
                                <li>Northwestern University</li>
                                <li>Penn State University</li>
                                <li>Quinnipiac University</li>
                                <li>Rider University</li>
                                <li>Rutgers University</li>
                                ​<li>Salisbury University</li>
                                <li>SUNY Albany</li>
                                <li>Syracuse University</li>
                                <li>The College of New Jersey</li>
                                <li>Tulane University</li>
                                ﻿<li>University of Delaware</li>
                                <li>University of Iowa</li>
                                <li>University of Maryland</li>
                                <li>University of Miami</li>
                                <li>University of Michigan</li>
                                <li>University of Pennsylvania</li>
                                <li>University of Richmond</li>
                                <li>University of Virginia</li>
                                <li>University of Wisconsin</li>
                                <li>Vanderbilt University</li>
                                <li>Virginia Tech</li>
                                <li>Washington and Lee University</li>
                                <li>Washington University (St. Louis)</li>
                                <li>William and Mary</li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you have some non printing unicode characters in there. If you paste that code into jsFiddle.net or bootply.com you'll see little red dots where you have problems.

Comment: Copied the code into Note++ and confirmed.  There are unprintable characters right before the `<li>` on a few lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some hidden text . I removed all text and it must be fine.. please copy and paste this list :

```
 <ul>
            <li>Binghamton University</li>
            <li>Boston University</li>
            <li>Carnegie Mellon University</li>
            <li>Colorado College</li>
            <li>Emory University</li>
            <li>Fairfield University</li>
            <li>Franklin & Marshall</li>
            <li>George Washington University</li>
            <li>Georgetown University</li>
            <li>Indiana University</li>
            <li>Ithaca College</li>
            <li>Kean University</li>
            <li>McGill University</li>
            <li>Northwestern University</li>
            <li>Penn State University</li>
            <li>Quinnipiac University</li>
            <li>Rider University</li>
            <li>Rutgers University</li>
            <li>Salisbury University</li>
            <li>SUNY Albany</li>
            <li>Syracuse University</li>
            <li>The College of New Jersey</li>
            <li>Tulane University</li>
            <li>University of Delaware</li>
            <li>University of Iowa</li>
            <li>University of Maryland</li>
            <li>University of Miami</li>
            <li>University of Michigan</li>
            <li>University of Pennsylvania</li>
            <li>University of Richmond</li>
            <li>University of Virginia</li>
            <li>University of Wisconsin</li>
            <li>Vanderbilt University</li>
            <li>Virginia Tech</li>
            <li>Washington and Lee University</li>
            <li>Washington University (St. Louis)</li>
            <li>William and Mary</li>
        </ul>
```